# Handle exceptions thrown by F# type provider in FSX script

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have an FSX script which includes a type provider. When the script is run, I would like to show a user-friendly message when the type provider throws an exception. (For example, when the `SqlDataProvider` cannot connect to the database.)

Is that possible?

This obviously won't work, but illustrates the idea:

```
type Sql =
    try
        SqlDataProvider< DatabaseVendor = databaseVendor, ConnectionString = connectionString, TableNames = tableNames >
    with ex ->
        printfn "Cannot connect to the database."
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/WallaceKelly/de7b741f32eb6aad192c989d04b3c20f) is a gist that can be used to test potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When the script runs, the exception will be thrown, but not until you use or instantiate the type from the Type Provider.

In your case, you wouldn't wrap the *definition* of the type in a try, but rather the usage:

```
type Sql = SqlDataProvider<...>

// When you go to _use_ the type, handle exceptions:
try
    let ctx = Sql.GetDataContext ()
    // .. use
with
| :? SomeExceptionType as ex -> printfn "Cannot connect to the database."
```

Comment: When I run the code in this gist with "Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.6.0.0 for F# 4.7", exception handling is not run... https://gist.github.com/WallaceKelly/de7b741f32eb6aad192c989d04b3c20f

Comment: @WallaceKelly Are you actually _using_ the context? I think the exception throws at runtime when the context access actually occurs.

Comment: I was not originally using it. However, I just updated the gist and re-tested. In both cases, the script fails with a _compiler_ error `FS3033`, never giveing the exception handling a chance to run.